# How can I write a function that will accept a list of any type (defined by a table) and add the contents of the list to the table?

Tags: c#, list, generics

How can I write a function that will accept a list of any type (defined by a table) and add the contents of the list to the table?

We are using a Unit of Work Repository pattern where `_entities` contains all the tables in our model.

Here I tried to use a generic list:

```
public void AddRows<T>(List<T> rows)
{
    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
       _entities.Table.Add(row); // this does not work, Table is just there to show what I'd like to do
    }            
}
```

Right now we have a separate method like this for any table in which we need to add rows. I'd like to remove some of this repetitiveness.

Here is what we have now (including only relevant details):

```
public void AddRowToMyTable(List<MyTable> rows)
{
    foreach(MyTable row in rows)
    {
        _entities.MyTable.Add(row);
    }
}
```

***edits***

Here is where entities is being declared:

```
   public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
    {
       IMyEntities _entities;
    }
```

Here is the IMyEntities class

```
public partial interface IMyEntities : IUnitOfWork
{
   IDbSet<MyTable> MyTable { get; }
      .
      .
      .
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `_entities` and `_entities.Table`?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSauder: _entities is a partial interface. It is used to hold the all the tables in our dB model.

Comment: So, each part includes, for instance, `ICollection<MyTable> MyTable {get;}`?

Comment: I was guessing. How about not making me guess? Go find out, then post a code example.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, that is correct see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to pass the table in:

```
public void AddRows<T>(ICollection<T> table, List<T> rows)
{
    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
       table.Add(row);
    }            
}
```

Comment: This snippet seems to work, but when I use _entities.table.Add(row); instead of table.Add(row); it throws an error saying "_entities does not contain a definition for 'table'...

Comment: Maybe _entities is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

In your unit of work, add:

```
public DbSet Set<T>() where T : class
{
    return _context.Set<T>();
}
```

Then do something like this:

```
public void AddRows<T>(List<T> rows) where T : class
{
    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
       _entities.Set<T>().Add(row);
    }            
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. VB says, "_entities does not contain a definition for 'Set'..."

Comment: @navig8tr I modified it. Check it out now.

Comment: @navig8tr I just noticed you are doing unit of work. I added some more code.

Comment: "This doesn't work. VB says..." I meant VS for Visual Studio. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @navig8tr You said you're using the `Unit of Work Repository` pattern. Add the first block of code to your `unitOfWork.cs` class and the `AddRows` in some other class.